# site map not reading javascript links

Tags: php, javascript, seo, sitemap

I have a strange problem and been onit most the week.

in my footer of my site i am using random links by use of java script

```
 <a class="default.php">Some Default Text</a>
```

and the javascript is

```
 <script>
 (function(){
  var myLinks = [
{href: 'example.php?title=hello', text: 'example1'},
{href: 'example.php?title=hello2', text: 'example2'}
];
onload = function(){
var link, pageLinkClass = 'myLink', pageLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
pageLinkClass = new RegExp('\\b' + pageLinkClass + '\\b');
for(var i = 0; i < pageLinks.length; ++i){
if(pageLinkClass.test(pageLinks[i].className)){
link = myLinks[Math.floor(Math.random() * myLinks.length)]
pageLinks[i].href = link.href;
pageLinks[i].firstChild.nodeValue = link.text;
pageLinks[i].target = '_self';
}
}
};
})();// JavaScript Document
</script>
```

(this is a example)

but when i crawl my site to generate a sitemap it only reads the links as example.php?title=

and not the trailing part.

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1):

Your crawler can not / does not interpret JavaScript. A lot of bots and crawlers will only read raw HTML. Google Bot can interpret JS to some extent, but I still wouldn't rely on it. Your best bet is to generate the links server side.

Comment: I updated my answer. You should generate these links on the server side and output them as HTML.

Comment: yes sorry i was to fast to reply, thanks for the help can you give me a link with instructions or more information (im quite new to all this)